# Android, Socket , connection server side .net and client side android?

Tags: android

How to connect a socket where server is in .net but Client is in Android ? 
after connectivity i want to send some data to server for login authentication after that server send to some response?

Comment: there is no difference in the language, in which the apps are written. Sockets work same way. To connect, you need to call `connect()` on a created socket. After that you can read and write data into it.

Comment: `there is no difference in the language, in which the apps are written.` ? The difference is java and .net. You ment : `it does not matter in which language the apps/sockets are written`. ;-).

Answer (score 0):

client Side
`private Socket socket;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";`

`try {
              String str = et.getText().toString();//EDIT TEXT OBJECT
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

`class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }`

using
`new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();`